# Knowing that $f(n)=n$, $g(n)=n\sqrt3$. Find $h(n)$ that contains all elements of $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ in ascending order.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Knowing that:

- $n$ is an integer going from zero to infinity,
- $f(n)=n$,
- $g(n)=n\sqrt3$.

I need a formula for $h(n)$ that can generate the series: $0, 1, \sqrt3, 2, 3, 2\sqrt3, 4, 5, 3\sqrt3, 6, 4\sqrt3 ... $ as a function of $n$.

$h(n)$ is a series that contains all elements of $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ in ascending order.

Comment: It starts at $n = 1$.

Comment: I have made the correction and included also the element $0$.

Answer (score 4):

You don't want the formula; it is going to be ugly.

.

.

.

.

.

.

Well, you've been warned. Have it, then:
$$h(n) = \min\left(\sqrt3\left\lceil{n\over1+\sqrt3}\right\rceil,\left\lceil{n\sqrt3\over1+\sqrt3}\right\rceil\right)$$

where $\lceil\cdot\rceil$ is of course the ceiling function.

Comment: that's a possibility too, at least it gives the same results than mine :-) I just went for full decomposition.

Comment: I believe yours is the same as mine, once you get rid of all those unnecessary intermediate variables. I started with a bunch of these too, then opted for greater clarity.

Comment: Your formula might be ugly but it is useful for finding the coordinates of all points of the double (aperiodic) grid of this problem: "Is it possible to draw all regular polygons on a double grid formed by a rational and an irrational grid, superimposed?" https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3995508/is-it-possible-to-draw-all-regular-polygons-on-a-double-grid-formed-by-a-rationa

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer to the question, but I did want to add a fun fact about the sequence. If you center a circle on a point in a triangular lattice, then this sequence describes the length of all possible radii in which the boundary of the circle touches only six points.

Answer (score 1):

The indices when roots appear seems to be [oeis.org/A054088](https://oeis.org/A054088)

Based on this I propose the following:

- $\phi(n)=n+\lfloor(n\sqrt{3})\rfloor\qquad$ the indices of $x\sqrt{3}$ numbers
- $\Phi(n)=\lceil\frac n{1+\sqrt{3}}\rceil\qquad$ the $x$ before $\sqrt{3}$, i.e. $\phi^{-1}$
- $\delta(n)=\Phi(n+1)-\Phi(n)\in\{0,1\}\qquad$ indicates that this $n$ is a root
- $N(n)=n+1-\Phi(n)\qquad$ the natural numbers mingled between the roots

The resulting formula:
$$h(n):\begin{cases}N(n)&\quad&\delta(n)=0\\\Phi(n)\sqrt{3}&&\delta(n)=1\end{cases}$$

Or without piecewise selection $h(n)=\delta(n)\Phi(n)\sqrt{3}+(1-\delta(n))N(n)$